# Count data Based on Account reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I Need Count data Based on Account name.(It means formula will refer the account name .i.e. Administration, Procurement etc and based on the same it will count the employee name as well as #N/A.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rewWK.png)

Your help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Vikkhe, what have you tried so far?

Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to format your question.

Comment: Ok Sir, i got your point.